# Table with sticky header using CSS Grid with table scroll and no page scroll

Tags: html, html-table, css-grid, css-tables

I've been trying to make a table that is scrollable without making the page scrollable, with fixed headers at the top.

I should not that I'm doing this inside a html component template.  So many of the ways that use divs instead of tables just wouldn't work at all (not sure why).

- I want the table to take up 100% of the view area
- Scrolling only within the table.
- Text in table cell should line wrap
- Pure HTML + CSS, no JS

So I'm currently trying to do this via a CSS grid layout for the table.

But this causes a few things:

- The table for some reason is longer than the page.
- The table is wider than the page in the TH tag and if the content has to line wrap
- The content is longer than the page, so when it scrolls it doesn't to show all text (it is worse than the demo code when I have a banner)

Demo code here:
https://codepen.io/element-of-surprise/pen/oNZvdqe

HTML:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="blah.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table class="someclass" id="historychange">
          <thead>
            <tr><th>Differences</th></tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><pre>...content...</pre></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If you scroll in the demo you'll see the header sticks until the very bottom and goes up, because it "thinks" it hit the end of content, which it hasn't yet.

Been staring at this in like 10 different ways for a while, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m not at a computer to try it but would adding `position: fixed` to the table element stop it from scrolling? Fixed works different that sticky.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It does, but the underlying problem of content then being scrolled beyond the scrollable area (which is what causes the sticky to not work right) happens.